# Unknown Unable to query docker version: Unable to read TLS config: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am experiencing a weird problem, I tried posting [this](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3842) it on github, so I might as well ask it in here too..

```
➜  ~ docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.8.2, build e18a919

➜  ~ docker-machine ls
NAME            ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                          SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
atago           -        google       Running   tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2376           Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Unable to read TLS config: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input
azure01         -        azure        Running   tcp://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:2376            Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Unable to read TLS config: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input
dev             -        virtualbox   Stopped                                        Unknown
dev01           -        google                                                      Unknown
jeanepaul-dev   -        google       Running   tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:2376            Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Unable to read TLS config: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input
```

I tried regenerating certs but,

```
➜  ~ docker-machine regenerate-certs -f azure01
Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
error generating server cert: tls: failed to parse private key
```

Comment: I dealed with this on the past. It was something about opens slightly version. If docker machine is local. Do a docker-machine ssh and disable tls in the configuration.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, It's remote.. to gcp and azure

Answer (score 3):

I  had  same  error while  I  was trying to  set up  HTTPS  for  Grafana. Because it  looks  to be  a  certificate related  issue and this  question was  not  answered  for  long time This  is  how  I solved  same problem  in case  of Grafana.

## 1  Migrate keystore from proprietary to pkcs12 format.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ./keystore -destkeystore ./keystore.pfx -deststoretype pkcs12 -storepass <storePass>
```

## 2  Extract keyStore.pem  - it  includes  certs  and  keys

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.pfx -out keyStore.pem -nodes
```

## 3 extract keys  only into pem format

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.pfx -out keyStore-keys.pem -nodes -nocerts
```

For  grafana I used only  files  generated  at  step 2 and 3

```
vi /path/to/grafana-5.2.1/conf/custom.ini
[server]
..
cert_file = "/path/to/grafana-5.2.1/conf/keyStore.pem"
cert_key = "/path/to/grafana-5.2.1/conf/keyStore-keys.pem"
```